# Is it possible to load a .js file inside a IIFE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm making HTML5 games using createJS and I have a main JS that has functions common to all other .js games and my code is inside:

```
(function () {
   var levelnumber = '<?php echo $level; ?>'; //it gets the starting level from the server
   var rightanswers = 0;
   ....

}());
```

So users in the console can't change the variables easily in the console, for example changing the level by changing the value of the variable levelnumber. I know that this won't prevent users from changing that variable, but it will just make it harder.

The thing is that I need to load a .js file via AJAX (I can't put the code inside the function because every .js file is a game and it will only load one game out of many). Since .js files needs to have access to functions and variables inside (function () { }()); it will give errors, and for example it needs access to the variable levelnumber to know which level to start.

So is there a way to load the .js file inside (function () {}()) so it wont give errors anymore?

Comment: No, there is not. Make the JS file export a function, and call that with your "private" variables.

Comment: Sorry, Can you explain better?

Comment: Wrap your js file in a function that takes all the value it needs as parameters. Then call that function with your local variables when it's loaded.